# Instanciar classe em uma library por método no arduino

Tags: c++, classes, arduino

Tenho essa linha de código, e nele eu tenho 2 métodos, onde um configura o keypad e outro pega a key pressionada.

```
void Maleta::setKeypad(int r1, int r2, int r3, int r4, int c1, int c2, int c3, int c4){
  const byte numRows= 4; // Numero de linhas
  const byte numCols= 4; // Numero de colunas

  char keymap[numRows][numCols]=
  {
   {'1','2','3','A'},
   {'4','5','6','B'},
   {'7','8','9','C'},
   {'*','0','#','D'},
  };

  byte rowPins[numRows] = {r1,r2,r3,r4}; // Pinos digitais onde as linhas estao conectadas
  byte colPins[numCols] = {c1,c2,c3,c4}; // Pinos digitais onde as colunas estao conectadas


  Keypad myKeypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keymap), rowPins, colPins, numRows, numCols);
}
char Maleta::getKeyPress(){
  char keypressed = myKeypad.getKey();
  return keypressed;
}
```

Esse é o erro que retorna:

> C:\Users\Luca\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Maleta\Maleta.cpp: In member
>   function 'char Maleta::getKeyPress()':
>
> C:\Users\Luca\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Maleta\Maleta.cpp:32:21:
>   error: 'myKeypad' was not declared in this scope
>   char keypressed = myKeypad.getKey();

Answer (score 0):

O problema está ocorrendo, pois a variável **myKeypad** não pode ser acessada dentro de **getKeyPress**, já que ela não é visível nesse escopo.

Note que a variável é declarada em outro método, chamado **setKeypad**. Os escopos dos métodos **getKeyPress** e **setKeypad** são distintos. Se **myKeypad** fosse uma variável global, aí sim ele poderia ser acessada, pois ela seria visível em todos os escopos do programa. Entretanto, variáveis globais, como regra geral, devem ser evitadas.

Answer (score 0):

```
char Maleta::getKeyPress(){
  //Exemplo Maleta2 mykeypad; voce teria declarada o mykeypad.
  char keypressed = myKeypad.getKey();// assim você chama mykeypad depois o membro .getKey()
  return keypressed;
}
```